# PHP switch "||" not working properly

Tags: php, switch-statement

In the switch statement, when i have a case with "||" it doesn't work properly.

```
$get = 'item';
switch ($get):

case 'items' || 'several-items':
    echo 'items';
    break;

case 'item':
    echo 'item';
    break;

endswitch;
```

This code outputs `items`. **Is this a php bug ?**

`$get = 'several';` outputs `items` too.

So the problem is definitely with the '||' operator, because **the following code works just fine**:

```
$get = 'item';
switch ($get):

case 'items':
case 'several-items':
    echo 'items';
    break;

case 'item':
    echo 'item';
    break;

endswitch;
```

Comment: No bug you can't use `||` or `&&` operators in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use OR (`||`) and AND (`&&`) operators in a switch statement

Comment: I saw "||" used when i searched on google, and first time worked fine so i taught that is corrent. My bad.

Comment: Actually you "can": `switch (true) { case ($get == 'items' || $get == 'severalitems'): }` but yeah don't ;)

Comment: That's no better than the if-elseif-else statement.

Comment: I never said it was ;-) As a matter of fact I was pretty explicit about the not doing this part :D

Answer (score 0):

Then use

```
case 'items':
case 'several-items':
    echo 'items';
    break;
```

instead, especially as that is the [documented method to use](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

otherwise you're testing against a case of the logical `or` of 'items' and 'several-items' (because `||` will always have the precedence), which is a boolean false; and your `$get` value will match that Boolean false unless it loose casts to a truthy value (ie is `1item` or similar)